# Java Servlet How to get UserId with Session

Tags: java

I'm trying to write user control script.

Users add some task and i want user to see his own tasks. In login page , this is the session part :

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", uname);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
```

And here is the task send part :

```
Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/covid?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8","root","");


                 PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(" insert 
                into gorevler(gorevtext,baslik) values(?,?)");
                 pst.setString(1, output);
                 pst.setString(2, output);
                 pst.executeUpdate();
```

I Want to send user id to database. Thus , user can list his own tasks. How can i do that?

Comment: `insert 
                into gorevler(gorevtext)(baslik) values(?,?)");` should be `insert 
                into gorevler(gorevtext,baslik) values(?,?)");`

Comment: how can i send user id to database

Comment: Do you want to capture the user ID from JSP and send to Servlet?

Comment: yes. thus , when user wants to see his own tasks , he can see.

Comment: You should add a column in the database for username and that way you are inserting gorevtext and baslik , same way you can send username also . Or May be create a different table for user information and insert it there after user sign up to your application.

Comment: yes. exactly , but how can i send username to database. How can i get username with session and what should be the SQL code?

Comment: You can use getAttribute method of Session class.

Answer (score 0):

You simply get the `username` attribute from the session, and use it like any other variable.

```
// Contrived example based on your posted example
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userName = session.getAttribute("username");
PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(" insert 
            into gorevler(gorevtext,baslik, username) values(?,?, ?)");
pst.setString(1, output);
pst.setString(2, output);
pst.setString(3, userName);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you. By the way , what about if we use userid instead of username. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use any name you want. The name is not important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

User Implicit session object to read session...

```
String userName=(String)session.getAttribute("username"); 
...
pst.setString(1, userName);
```